# Can anyone help get Simplegeo -ruby client working in Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, rubygems

I have installed the [simplegeo-ruby gem](https://github.com/simplegeo/simplegeo-ruby) and have been able to get this working through the Rails console, successfully creating records with the these commands:

(Note - I'm looking up the address via geokit and Google first)

```
>> @record = Record.new(:address => 'Address')
>> geocoded = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode @record.address
    record = SimpleGeo::Record.new({
     :id => @record.id,
     :created => Time.now,
     :lat => geocoded.lat,
     :lon => geocoded.lng,
     :layer => 'com.mylayer.records',
   })
>> SimpleGeo::Client.add_record(record)
```

However my app is breaking when attempting to create a new record and throwing this error:

```
SimpleGeo::NotFound 
app/controllers/records_controller.rb:24:in `create'
```

My RecordsController#create action looks like this:

```
def create
@record = Record.new(params[:record])
geocoded = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode @record.address
  record = SimpleGeo::Record.new({
    :id => @record.id,
    :created => Time.now,
    :lat => geocoded.lat,
    :lon => geocoded.lng,
    :layer => 'com.mylayer.records',
  })
  SimpleGeo::Client.add_record(record)
if @record.save
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created record."
  redirect_to @record
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
end
```

Any help or references using Simplegeo with Rails 3 are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the simplegeo gem in your `Gemfile`? And have you ran `bundle install` command? This is usually the problem when I've come across errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

Is your layer called "com.mylayer.records"? That is usually just an example layer.

Create your own layers here: http://simplegeo.com/layers

If you cannot see that page, then you don't have access to the private beta of SimpleGeo Storage. It should be in the public in a few months though.

If you want to geocode addresses in the US, use SimpleGeo's /1.0/context endpoint: http://simplegeo.com/docs/api-endpoints/simplegeo-context#get-context

Comment: Just used that for the example. I have my own layer and am using that in the code. Things seem to work if I save the record to my database before trying to create the simplegeo record. do i need to move the simplegeo creation to a new separate controller?